# Program not running, possible method error

Tags: java, methods

```
public class Power{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Power p = new Power();

       int length = 6;
       p.square( length );
       p.cube( length );
       p.hypercube( length );
   }
}
```

Hey i'm trying to do the following program, but can't get it to run. I'm receiving an error on the p's in `p.square`,`p.cube` and `p.hypercube`. I think the reason is because they haven't got their own individual methods referring to, therefore at the moment they're non-existent. I've been trying to add methods for square, cube and hypercube but still receiving errors. Not seeming to get anywhere, hopefully someone can help. Cheers.

Comment: Why do you try to do things without knowing what you are doing? You want to call a method, have you declared that method?

Comment: Please post an actual error message.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my best guess:

You can't run the program (or your compiler will produce errors/red underlined pieces of code) if you don't declare the functions you're calling in your class first.

```
public class Power{ /*Complete*/

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Power p = new Power();

        int length = 6;

        p.square( length );
        p.cube( length );
        p.hypercube( length );
    }

    private void square(int length) {
        //do whatever you want with your argument length
    }

    private void cube(int length) {
        //do whatever you want with your argument length
    }

    private void hypercube(int length) {
        //do whatever you want with your argument length
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create method. What you want  to do ?

If you want to make square you can write something like:

```
public int square(int length)
{
  int q;
  q= length*length;

  return q;
}
```